# How to make Resharper place blank lines after { in c#

Tags: resharper, resharper-5.0

Does anyone know how to make Resharper add blank lines after brackets when performing code cleanup?

I want to make the following code

```
if (x == y)
{
   int a = x;
   int b = y;
   int z = a + b;
}
```

Look like this

```
if (x == y)
{

   int a = x;
   int b = y;
   int z = a + b;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a look through the Resharper options but can't see anything to add the extra blank lines around your block of code, although I am not sure that format makes it any more readable than without extra spaces. I would suggest asking this question on the Resharper News Group: [**news://news.jetbrains.com/jetbrains.resharper.community**](http://tinyurl.com/3369sch)

Comment: Thanks for the information, but it looks like there is not an option that supports this.  Since adding an extra blank line does not overly enhance readability I will accept the default.